# Disable confirmation questions when copying mass files on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

Where in Windows XP (SP2) can one disable questions, or the confirmation dialogs that pop up, before copying a large sum of files?

I want to be able to set up a mass copy and not be bothered by or get stuck in midtransfer with a confirmation asking something along the lines of:

> This file is read only. Do you wish to continue copying?

Basically I want to suppress any such warnings and let it continue copying all the files across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't disable these questions, i do recommend **[TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php)** or **[FastCopy](http://www.ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en)** instead of Windows file copy, not only are they much faster than anything Windows has to offer, but also much more comfortable.

TeraCopy can be integrated into the context menu and used within Windows Explorer.

*TeraCopy and FastCopy are freeware.*

Comment: Are you sure about not being able to disable them ? I know of Tera/Fastcopy, but unfortunatelly, the computers in question which I have to take care off, are not mine ... otherwise, they're nice little proggies.

Comment: unless you disable the system file checker ... which might have an even worse impact on the relation between you and the owner of the computer than installing Teracopy :) http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/wfp.mspx#E4H

Answer (score 1):

If you're prepared to not use Windows Explorer I think you want the [`xcopy`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) command.

There are various options that you might find useful:

> /C           Continues copying even if errors occur.
>   /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
>                existing destination file.

Comment: Uhmm ... no. I didn't perhaps state it explicitly. I was hoping to avoid them while copying files in windows explorer.

Comment: @Idigas This is a proper solution. Windows explorer is for detail jobs. If you do not like pesky prompts, the command line is the way to go. If you need a window, i think you can use software like totalcommander which is somewhat similar to normal Windows explorer but will definitely give you an ability to move files in bulk without unnecessary prompts.